# How do I sum the lowest two values of two different column or range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, nest

I have a column ranging `D27` to `D34`, I want to sum the 3 lowest values of cell `D27` to `D30` and 1 lowest value of cell `D31` to `D34`.

I started with this formula:

```
=SUM(SMALL(D25:D30,{1,2,3}))
```

But only get sum for one range. I don't know how to complete the formula for two ranges.

I tried:

```
=SUM(SMALL(D25:D30,{1,2,3})),(SMALL(D31:D34))
```

It didn't work, and I think I wrote nonsense.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome! What about a normal MIN() for the second range and then sum them up `=SUM(SMALL(D25:D30;{1;2;3});MIN(D31:D34))` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, i tried with 2 values for both also with SMALL(), that also worked, must have been a character misplaced, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with the first part is that you are finding two permanent 0's with `SMALL` (1,2) and finally one value of some kind (3).

The reason is that your values begin in D27 but the `SMALL` function is told to look beginning in D25. Presumably D25 and D26 have 0's (actual 0's, text, blank cells...) so the two smallest values in the range are their 0's, and then the third smallest value is one of the actually desired values.

Simply fixing the range will make your formula work as desired.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.     *"Simply fixing the range"* will **not** make the formula work.  Largely irrelevant, but, there is also no evidence in the question of any issue with the range.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> =SUM(SMALL(D25:D30,{1,2,3})),(SMALL(D31:D34))
> ```

## 3 Issues

1. SUM function's first argument contains an extra closing bracket:

   - `SMALL(array, k))` should be `SMALL(array, k)`
2. SUM function's second argument contains an extra opening bracket

   - `(SMALL(array, k)` should be `SMALL(array, k)`
3. Second SMALL function is missing the `k` argument

   - `SMALL(array)` should be `SMALL(array, k)`

With those corrections, the formula should work as intended:

```
=SUM(SMALL(D25:D30,{1,2,3}),
     SMALL(D31:D34,1))
```

Per [JohnSUN's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1784335/how-do-i-sum-the-lowest-two-values-of-two-different-column-or-range#comment2788164_1784335), you might optionally replace `SMALL(D31:D34,1)` with `MIN(D31:D34)`

```
=SUM(SMALL(D25:D30,{1,2,3}),
     MIN(D31:D34))
```